# UWP: No MouseDown event on Ellipse? (Windows 10 IoT | C#)

Tags: c#, uwp, raspberry-pi, win-universal-app, windows-10-iot-core

Currently I am working on an application in C# for my Raspberry Pi 3 with Windows 10 IoT. I selected "Blank App (Universal Windows)" when I created the program (I was following a tutorial of the Microsoft Dev Center). Since then I ran into some problems.

First the timer directive wasn't available. (`using System.Timers`)
I tried to import a new `System.dll` but VS won't let me do that, because there is already one implemented. So i thought maybe this is just a thing for this kind of application I choose at the beginning. Does anybody know why I can't find the timer class?

But know to my main problem:
I would like to click on the ellipses on my user interface. While googling I noticed there is no click event for the ellipses, but there must be a `MouseUp` or `MouseDown`, but it looks like my program doesn't know these events... 
If anybody knows an answer for my problem, thanks in advance.
(I would like to bypass the solution with creating a button and then shape it like an ellipse because I would have to do that for 72 ellipses in my application and I am to lazy to do that ;-) . But if there is no other way i will have to do it that way)

And if anybody needs more information, please feel free to ask.

Thanks,
Heenne

Comment: The events you're looking for are PointerPressed and PointerReleased. Easy to find in the [online documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.shapes.ellipse). Note that UWP and WPF are different frameworks.

Comment: In UWP you can use `System.Threading.Timer`.

Comment: In case you're periodically updating the UI, better use DispatcherTimer.